# Cypress testing a form

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I am testing a form using Cypress. I need to get a pop up during testing only to enter one of the input fields in the form because it should be a unique value and it should be different each time I run the test. How to write the test script in Cypress for this? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: I am not exactly understand what you want to achieve. Who is opening the pop up? What is your exactly problem? The pop up? Or top find an unique value? What do you have tried so far?

Comment: Yes I am confused also. Can you give us more information. Is the popup a modal?

Comment: There are a number of input fields in the form in which one value is unique.
Say the input field CSS class is 'unique_id'. Then I call the field as, cy.get('.unique_id').type('123456')
Since the value should be unique, each time I run the test, I need to edit the value in the code. Instead of doing this, to fully automate the test, I would like to get a pop up to type the value then return back to the test. I don't know whether it is possible or not. Or suggest me other options to automate. Hope it is clear this time. Thank you for your consideration and time.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that, you might have a form where you need to enter a `unique` number in a text field every time while you are calling the form.

The below javascript pass a unique number to a `const uniqueValue` each time, just pass that `const value` into the type field;

```
describe('Test for unique value', () => {
    it('Receive unique value always in text input', () => {
     const uniqueValue = (new Date()).getTime() + Math.trunc(365 * Math.random());
     console.log(uniqueValue); 
     cy.wait(2000)
     cy.visit('some_url_here')
     cy.get('#yourtextinput').type(uniqueValue);
    })
```

Another way is create a javascript function separately and assign this into a 
`const myUnique = getUniquevalue();` in cypress test. Pass this `myUnique` in type command in cypress.

```
function getUniquevalue(){
 const uniqueValue = (new Date()).getTime() + Math.trunc(365 * Math.random());
 return uniqueValue;
}
```

see below console output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you only want to type a unique value each time you execute your tests, rather than manually editing the hardcoded one. And you achieve this by opening some other forms(popup at your case) as a workaround. Well, you should generate a UIID for this purpose within your code.

UUIDs (Universally Unique IDentifier), also known as GUIDs (Globally Unique IDentifier), according to RFC 4122, are identifiers with a certain uniqueness guarantee.

The simplest way to achieve this is to import an npm package and use it. There are many packages for this, you may do a search to pick one. One of them is changejs (includes many other features as well..). Check out this https://chancejs.com/miscellaneous/guid.html